# Main Page Browser Caching in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

The problem I'm facing in my asp.net is when I logged in successfully and I copied the default page on another browser, the browser displays the default page. The other browser should display Login page. I'm using the below code in my site master but unfortunately its not working

```
  Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

  Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
  Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you open a new browser, go to the page and login, after that you open a new tab in the same browser and would like to be logout again to display the login page or?

Comment: No. After I login, I copy it on another browser. Like for example I logged in successfully in google chrome and I copied the link to IE, the page shown is the Default page instead of Login.

Comment: It's nothing to do with caching, pages cached in chrome have no affect on IE.

Comment: So, what can you suggests I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you checking the identity of authenticated users. have you denying anonymous users from web.config file? or you have some kind of session or other checks on every page? What you can do is just create a BasePage and check your security from this..

Comment: I'm using if(Session["user"] != null){*code*}else{*back to login*} on Master Page

Comment: You should add this line in your web.config file also to deny anonymous uses<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>